# Output Channel entries on another page with a matrix block

Tags: templating, entries, matrix

I know im doing something small wrong but I cant see what at this point.

I have a channel called 'testimonialEntries' and I want to randomly output one of these entries on seperate pages. I cant output the matrix block in 'testimonialEntries' but i can the title, so i know its working just not accessing the matrix block.

```
{% for entries in craft.entries.section('testimonalEntries').orderBy('RAND()').limit(1).all() %}
{% block in entry.matrixBlock %}
<article>
    <h4>{{ block.heading }}</h4>]
    <p>{{ block.bodyContent }}</p>
</article>
{% endfor %}{% endfor %}
```

In this example im getting the entry title, but how do i also get a matrix block?

Edit: AM I getting close?

```
{% set testimonialEntry = craft.entries.section('testimonalEntries').orderBy('RAND()').limit(1).with(['testimonial']).one() %}
{% set testimonialEntryMatrixBlocks = testimonialEntry.testimonial %}
    {% if testimonialEntryMatrixBlocks %}
    <article>
        <p>{{ testimonialEntryMatrixBlocks.body }}</p>
        <p>{{ testimonialEntryMatrixBlocks.quote }}</p>
        <p>{{ testimonialEntryMatrixBlocks.role }}</p>
    </article>
    {% endif %}
```

Ok final edit incase anyone else runs across this: It Works!

```
    {% set testimonialEntry = craft.entries.section('testimonalEntries').orderBy('RAND()').limit(1).with(['testimonial']).one() %}
{% set testimonialEntryMatrixBlocks = testimonialEntry.testimonial %}
    {% if testimonialEntryMatrixBlocks %}
        {% for testimonial in testimonialEntryMatrixBlocks %}
        <article>
            <p>{{ testimonial.body }}</p>
            <p>{{ testimonial.quote }}</p>
            <p>{{ testimonial.role }}</p>
        </article>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for a loop if you're just fetching a single entry:

```
{% set testimonialEntry = craft.entries.section('testimonalEntries').orderBy('RAND()').limit(1).one() %}
{% set testimonialEntryMatrixBlocks = testimonialEntry.matrixField.all() %}
```

Ideally for better performance you'd also use [eager loading](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/dev/eager-loading-elements.html) to load the matrix blocks at the same time as fetching the entry:

```
{% set testimonialEntry = craft.entries.section('testimonalEntries').orderBy('RAND()').limit(1).with(['matrixField']).one() %}
{% set testimonialEntryMatrixBlocks = testimonialEntry.matrixField %}
```

Comment: I've added what ive being using, im abit unsure how to go about using {% set %} though? Thank you

Comment: If you've never used `{% set %}` before, I'd recommend that you spend some time getting familiar with the basics of Twig, otherwise you're going to run into a lot of frustration! The Craft docs give a quick primer: https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/dev/twig-primer.html or go straight to the official docs: https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x - You're also going to need to understand the difference between arrays and strings for a better understanding of how to code in Twig.